# Trouble using a dictionary object in GAS

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to build a mode-like function for strings. I thought I could build a dictionary like this (where a is passed in and is a range of strings):

```
var b={};
for (i in a) {
   h=a[i];
   try {b[h]++;}
   catch (err) {b[h]=1;}
}
```

but it isn't working. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think an error is being thrown. I did it this way.

```
var b = {};
for(var i in a){
  if(typeof b[a[i]] === 'undefined')
    b[a[i]] = 1;
  else
    b[a[i]]++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To fit your code I'd also add a counter, like this

```
var b={};
for (i=0;i<a.length,i++) {
   h=a[i];
   try {b[h]=i+1}
   catch (err) {b[h]=1;}
}
```

At the end of loop you'll have something like:

```
b = {
a[0]: 1, // a[0] will be whatever value you have at first position
a[1]: 2, // a[1] will be whatever value you have at second position
...
}
```

Comment: I actually tried that but it didn't work. Either way, b stays empty.